# How to set Background image for iphone app in phonegap

Tags: iphone, html, cordova

I am new in phonegap development and i am developing one project for iphone application with use of phonegap framework.

I am setting http://www.wallpaperbase.com/wallpapers/computer/mac/mac_8.jpg  image as a background of my iphone application but its showing problem with image means image not properly displaying on my iphone Device like as given image example below.

Please solve my issue ASPS.

[image]

Please check my [code](http://www.mediafire.com/?ngxbrb40v0176s6) and let me know what's wrong in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to try this on line number 15 in index.html page-

```
<body style="background: url(mac_8.jpg) no-repeat;background-size: 100%;" >
```

then your app's background image will look like this -

[image: landscape mode]
[image: portrait mode]

only if you made changes in info.plist to support for landscape mode for iPhone

One important thing - take background image of size 320X480 or 640X940 (iPhone4)

Comment: Dear sir,Thanks for your reply pls suugest me what imaze size should i take for android phone? and is there any way to contact you regarding phone gap problem?

Comment: depends on your android phone screen resolution.

Comment: I actually tried the code above, it didn't work for me, still see white background for page, any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Same problem here…!?!