# Set background image in PhoneGap not working

Tags: cordova

I tried to use the solution in this post but still not working and the result is white page

[How to set Background image for iphone app in phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509796/how-to-set-background-image-for-iphone-app-in-phonegap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using this CSS code, it works for me fine :

```
.ui-page.ui-body-c {
        background: url("img/J-BigBox.png");
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:left center;
        background-size:cover;

    }

    .ui-page {
        background: transparent;

    }
    .ui-content{
        background: transparent;

    }
```